# Terminating request.post in a middle of a connection while using multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-requests, multiprocessing

Right now the logic is this:

Multiprocess request.posts till we get required response
Set event to stop and terminate processes

BUT, the requests that were executed before termination still finishes their job, which i can't afford. I need them stopped exact second as my condition is finished. I can even afford killing network adapter for the script for a second, if thats what it takes. I just need to get on the right track

This is on Windows, Running python 2.7, Multiprocessing and Requests libs

Is there any way to stop connections of Requests module in the middle of requests? (Need to stop all of them running on different processes)

For example:

```
def worker(found_event):
    print 'process started'
    randDelay = random.randint(4, 10)
    response = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/delay'+str(randDelay))
    print response.status_code
    found_event.set()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    found_event = Event()

    pool = [Process(target=worker, args=(found_event,)) for i in range(10)]

    for p in pool:
        p.start()

    found_event.wait()
    for p in pool:
        p.terminate()
    for p in pool:
        p.join()
```

Sometimes returns :

```
process started
process started
process started
process started
process started
process started
process started
process started
process started
process started
404
```

Sometimes:

```
process started
process started
process started
process started
process started
process started
process started
process started
process started
process started
404404
```

Comment: can you include some code example?

Comment: Added code example